# PHP/SQL Server: Change <div> color according to time

Tags: php, css, sql, sql-server

I created a PHP page for booking room. In that booking, it has a scheduler for each meeting room. The scheduler is viewed by day and the time format is 24 hours.

So in my SQL database, there are two columns for the time which is 'StartTime' and 'EndTime'.

Let say, if time now is 2019-09-04 09:26:00.000 the booking time is from 'StartTime' = 2019-09-04 06:00:00.000 and end 'EndTime' at 2019-09-04 10:00:00.000, the div color is green because the booked is running.

But if time now is 2019-09-04 14:00:00.000 the div color will change to grey because the meeting already passed.

Below is just my simple code for testing

```
<html>
<thead>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php 

    require_once('configPDO.php');
    $query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM booking ORDER BY Book_No DESC");
    while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $end = $row['EndTime'];

        if($end == GETDATE()){
            $color="background-color:green";
        }
        else if ($end > GETDATE()){
            $color="background-color:blue";
        }else{
            $color="background-color:grey";
        }

        echo "<div style='$color'>".$end."</div><br>";
    }

?>

</tbody>
</html>
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is easier to handle. getting the logic within your sql query.

```
 <?php 

    require_once('configPDO.php');
    $query = $conn->query("SELECT *, case when getdate() between StartTime and EndTime then '1' when StartDate > getdate() then '2' else '0' end as rColor FROM booking ORDER BY Book_No DESC");
        while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $rColor = $row['rColor'];


    if($rColor == "1"){
        $color="background-color:green";
    }
    else if ($rColor  == "2"){

        $color="background-color:blue";

    }else{
        $color="background-color:grey";
    }

    echo "<div style='$color'>".$row['EndTime']."</div><br>";

    }
?>
```

**Note**: if our `EndTime` column is not `datetime`, cast it first before making logical operation to `getdate()` or `current_date()` (MySQL)

Comment: if the meeting is running, the div is blue, when the meeting didn't start yet, it also blue but if meeting already passed, it will change to grey. can you fix your code?

Comment: updated to EndTime > getdate() or StartTime > getdate(), so it will be blue

Comment: try now, i only changed the green one. try to echo $rColor first and tell me the ouput

Comment: Solve !! but why need to do the condition in the query?

Comment: Because like almost everything in programming, there's more than one way to solve a problem. I would advocate to remove the logic from the query and do it in PHP where code belongs, but that's just me.